# Indicators for New Favorite Tags Questions

Tags: feature-request

I think it would be great to add "new" indicators when new questions appear for our favorite tags (similar to email inbox indicators).

This would improve the workflow for users who provide support to topics they know well and reduces time by eliminating the need to click each topic to visually inspect for new questions.  The indicators would immediately show from the home screen, and indicators would be removed after you view the topic page and see the questions.  Here's a mock up:

[image]

Comment: Just to verify: does that counter work similar as if you had opened a tab with questions/tagged/[some tag] where it would show [3 new questions] after a while?

Comment: That feature already exists, use the RSS feed.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags

Comment: Oh.. you mean a 'down and close vote required' flag:(

Comment: SO is currently not looking for ideas to help answerers, only ones that help new users feel more welcome. It may be a long time before this one gets any kind of status tag added to it.